# Copying a linked list onto another linked list - iteratively - C - understanding the returned list

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

Trying my hand at linked list problems, and for today I'm trying "given a linked list, copy it to another linked list"

For doing this iteratively,

The logic would be
- Use three pointers - current, newList, newTail.

`current` to keep track of the *current node* in the given, original list.

`newList` to keep track of the *head* of the list that I'm copying to.

`Tail` to keep the track of *tail* of the list I'm copying to.

- When the new list is empty, create a new node and copy the head, always have `tail` pointing to the last node.

To that end, my copy list function **should supposedly** look like this -

```
struct node* CopyList(struct node* head) {
   struct node* current = head; // used to iterate over the original list
   struct node* newList = NULL; // head of the new list
   struct node* tail = NULL; // kept pointing to the last node in the new list

   while (current != NULL) {
     if (newList == NULL) { // special case for the first new node
       newList = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       newList->data = current->data;
       newList->next = NULL;
       tail = newList;
     }
    else {
       tail->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       tail = tail->next;
       tail->data = current->data;
       tail->next = NULL;
     }
     current = current->next;
     }
return(newList);
}
```

My question is:
If I `return(newList)` ,I will have only one node, won't I?
Because I'm advancing `Tail` if the new list is not empty, shouldn't I return `Tail` instead of `newList` ?

Comment: Your code _looks_ just fine (didn't run it to test though). You will return a pointer to the head of the copied list, and if there are other nodes, they will be pointed to by the previous ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the first element in the list `newList` and `tail` point to the same address (`tail = newList`).

Each time you add another element you add it after `tail` and then move it to the next position (`tail = tail->next`). That is, when you add the second element, `tail` which was `newList` will now be `newList->next`.

This way, you can return `newList` and have all the pointers point to the next element in the list.

Comment: So this would be equivalent to returning tail? Or should I compulsorily return newList ?

Comment: Ah never mind, I understood. Tail is advancing and it would be the end of the list, where as newList is the header and thus includes pointer to the entire new list created by moving tail in each iteration.

Comment: Yep, that's why you always return `newList` instead of `tail`. Returning `tail` (or any other element in the list) will not get you the elements before it.